# Цвет текста в зависимости от условия React

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Имеется элемент  `<label htmlFor="inputUsername" >{(username) ?'V':'X' }</label>`
В зависимости от условия необходимо указать цвет возращенного значения. Если `'V'` - то зеленый. Если `'X'` - то красный.
Подскажите пожалуйста, мерси.

Comment: `<label htmlFor="inputUsername" style={{color: username ? 'green' : 'red' }}>{(username) ?'V':'X' }</label>`

Comment: О, Спасибо, то что нужно)